# Adding data to element in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am reading data and outputting it into an interactive printer map. The printer positioning data contains the x coordinate, y coordinate, make, model, and IP of the printers. I create an image using this data and position it. The problem is is that I'm trying to figure out some way to bind the make, model, and IP to the image so I can read it easily in future interactions with it. For example, something like this would be nice:
`printerImage.Attribute("Make", "HP");`
Is this possible/advisable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create yourself class if you haven't already done so that has all the properties you need, your data source may already be providing such an object.

All `FrameworkElements` including `Image` have a `Tag` property to be used for your exact reason.

```
printerImage.Tag = instanceOfYourPrinterInfoClass;
```

You can then retreive the info you need with:-

```
YourPrinterInfoClass info = printerImage.Tag as YourPrinterInfoClass;
```

**Edit**

Having said that possibly a better place than `Tag` to assign the object is `DataContext`.  You could for example then add a Tooltip that renders these details when the mouse hovers over the image.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you are using `System.Windows.Controls.Image`, correct? In that case it's a `DependencyObject`, so you can define and set attached properties on it.

```
public static class PrinterImageExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrinterMakeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PrinterMake", typeof(string), typeof(ImageExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static string GetPrinterMake(Image obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(PrinterMakeProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPrinterMake(Image obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PrinterMakeProperty, value);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then use the attached properties like this:

```
PrinterImageExtensions.SetPrinterMake(printerImage, "HP");
```

Comment: That seems like a lot for such simplistic functionality. Do you know of any other ways to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately attached properties do come with quite a bit of boilerplate code. The getter and setter aren't strictly required if you're not using the property in xaml. If you got rid of them you'd need to call `printerImage.SetValue(PrinterMakeProperty, "HP")` to set the value, or `(string)printerImage.GetValue(PrinterMakeProperty)` to get the value. Also you could define the attached property in the class that uses it rather than in its own static class.

Comment: @HiTech: Attached properties are just simply not a good fit for this task.  Even if an attached property were to used we wouldn't want to create a plethora of them, one for each aspect of a printer.  Rather we'd create one that held a specific "PrinterInfo" type.  Even then I see no benefit to using an attached property for this job.  Sometimes we can be a little apt to apply clever techonologies even when the good old fashioned ones work as well or even better.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Agreed. I answered the question with a solution that fit very closely to what the submitter was trying to do, but using the DataContext with a model object is better for this situation. +1 to your answer.